# Programmatically get descriptions of python function arguments

Tags: python, arguments

Let's say I have the following function:

```
def get_fullname(first: str, last: str = "Miller"):
    """
    :param first: First name
    :param last: Last name
    :return: Fullname
    """
    return f"{first} {last}"
```

I know I can get a bunch of information about the function using the `inspect` module:

```
import inspect
spec = inspect.getfullargspec(get_fullname)
print(spec)
# FullArgSpec(args=['first', 'last'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=('Miller',), kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={'first': <class 'str'>, 'last': <class 'str'>})
```

Is there anyway I can programmatically get the descriptions for these arguments? Doesn't look it's possible but just making sure. Looks like this is a PyCharm way of [specifying types](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docstrings-to-specify-types.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install and use [`docstring_parser`](https://pypi.org/project/docstring-parser/):

```
import docstring_parser

def get_fullname(first: str, last: str = "Miller"):
    """
    :param first: First name
    :param last: Last name
    :return: Fullname
    """
    return f"{first} {last}"

doc = docstring_parser.parse(get_fullname.__doc__)
for param in doc.params:
    print(param.arg_name, param.description)
print(doc.returns.description)
```

This outputs:

```
first First name
last Last name
Fullname
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in `.__doc__` attribute on things like functions and classes too (no installing extra modules). For instance:

```
def get_fullname(first: str, last: str = "Miller"):
    """
    :param first: First name
    :param last: Last name
    :return: Fullname
    """
    return "{first} {last}"
print(get_fullname.__doc__)
```

Yields:

```
    :param first: First name
    :param last: Last name
    :return: Fullname
```

Not sure if this is what you are intending to find though. This just prints the docstring directly, and doesn't parse it like @blhsing's answer